# How to calculate STD dev and Average with linq and entity framework at the same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Hello I would like to ask you is there a way to calculate average and std deviation at the same time with LINQ.

```
var players = new List<Player>
{
    new Player { Name = "Alex", Team = "A", Score = 10 },
    new Player { Name = "Anna", Team = "A", Score = 20 },
    new Player { Name = "Luke", Team = "L", Score = 60 },
    new Player { Name = "Lucy", Team = "L", Score = 40 },
};

var teamAverageScores =
    from player in players
    group player by player.Team into playerGroup
    select new
    {
        Team = playerGroup.Key,
        AverageScore = playerGroup.Average(x => x.Score),
    };
```

I would like to calculate in this example the STDev for the score and return two different list one for the average and one for the standard deviation.

Expected result for `AverageScore`:

```
{ Team = "A", AverageScore = 15.0 } 
{ Team = "L", AverageScore = 50.0 }
```

And for std dev:

```
{ Team = "A", STDScore = 5.0 } 
{ Team = "L", STDScore = 10.0 }
```

Comment: Can you show what would be your desired result?

Comment: I would like to have a list for average  { Team = "A", AverageScore = 15.0 }
// { Team = "L", AverageScore = 50.0 } and list for std dev { Team = "A", STDScore = 2.0 }
// { Team = "L", STDScore = 3.0 } this is just an example not precise values

Comment: Are you sure about the values of STDDev? I have found a solution for you, but in my calculations I am getting 5 and 10 as STDDev based on your inputs.

Comment: yeah that's what i mentioned it's only for the example so it's not a correct output, but please if u have a solution i am glad that u can share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after several tries

```
var teamAverageScores =
        from player in players
        group player by player.Team into playerGroup
        select new
        {
            Team = playerGroup.Key,
            AverageScore = playerGroup.Average(c => c.Score),
            STDev =  (playerGroup.Count() == 1) ? 0 : Math.Sqrt(playerGroup.Sum(b => Math.Pow(playerGroup.Score - playerGroup.Average(c => c.Score), 2)) / (g.Count() - 1)),,
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://www.developer.com/net/article.php/3794146/Adding-Standard-Deviation-to-LINQ.htm), you need to use an extension method like this:

```
public static class ExtensionsClass
{
    public static double CalculateStdDev(this IEnumerable<double> values)
    {
        double ret = 0;
        int count = values.Count();
        if (count > 1)
        {
            //Compute the Average
            double avg = values.Average();

            //Perform the Sum of (value-avg)^2
            double sum = values.Sum(d => (d - avg) * (d - avg));

            //Put it all together
            ret = Math.Sqrt(sum / count);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var teamAverageScores =
     from player in players
     group player by player.Team into playerGroup
     select new
     {
         Team = playerGroup.Key,
         AverageScore = playerGroup.Average(c => c.Score),
         STDev = playerGroup.Select(c => c.Score).CalculateStdDev(),
     };
```

Comment: Extension methods of `IEnumerable<T>` should not enumerate the source more than once, because it is possible (and quite frequent) that the underlying data are not stored in memory but are fetched from a database (or from the filesystem or from a web API). An easy fix is to replace `IEnumerable<int>` with `ICollection<int>`, since a container of this type is most certainly stored in memory.

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double StdDev(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Double])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'
This is what i am getting on the run time

Comment: @ZaatourWadi Use `ToList()` after `Select` and before `Calculate`.

Comment: same error because i think IEnumerable cannot be used inside the select because it cannot be converted

Comment: @ZaatourWadi What about this? `var teamAverageScores =
                (from player in players
                group player by player.Team into playerGroup select playerGroup).ToList().Select(playerGroup => new
                {
                    Team = playerGroup.Key,
                    AverageScore = playerGroup.Average(c => c.Score),
                    STDev = playerGroup.Select(c => c.Score).CalculateStdDev(),
                });`

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework by any chance, @ZaatourWadi? I don't otherwise see why you'd get a `LINQ to Entities` error.

Comment: yeah I am using EF

Comment: Can you please update the question to include that? That information is quite important as Salah has answered this question believing that it is a simple LINQ query (Please correct me if I'm wrong @SalahAkbari) and such a query won't work in Entity Framework.

Comment: @ColinM Yes, that's why I have suggested to use `ToList()` in order to do the further operation in memory. However I can't guarantee the performance in this approach.

Comment: because I am using Entity framework in this case this solution dosen't work

Comment: @ZaatourWadi Indeed it works if you can use the ToList correctly as mentioned already.

Comment: To make it work with EF you probably need to convert `ToList` each individual grouping, not just the enumerable of all groupings. But I may be wrong (don't know much about EF).

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution would be to use the NuGet package [LinqStatistics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqStatistics/) to calculate the standard deviation scores, and [`Enumerable.Average()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=netframework-4.8) from LINQ to calculate the average scores. If you don't like using external libraries, then [@Salah Akbari's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60967960/how-to-calculate-std-dev-and-average-with-linq-and-entity-framework-at-the-same/60968433#60968433) solution will be a better fit. I thought it was a good idea to bring this library up, since I've used it in the past with no problems.

```
using LinqStatistics;

// Other code

// Class that stores results from query
// Might be cleaner than using an anonymous class
public class Result
{
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public double Average { get; set; }
    public double StdDev { get; set; }
}

var teamAverageScores = players
    .GroupBy(player => player.Team)
    .Select(grp => new Result
    {
         Team = grp.Key,
         Average = grp.Average(player => player.Score),
         StdDev = grp.StandardDeviation(player => player.Score)
    });
```

Try on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2G72GY)

**Note:** The above uses LINQ *method syntax* fully, instead of *query syntax*. You can read about the differences between these different syntax types at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq). Using either comes down to preference.

Comment: thanks for the response but I am avoiding using external libraries

Comment: The OP is using Entity Framework. Their source is not actually a `List<Player>`, so most probably the `StandardDeviation` operator will not be recognized by the EF machinery.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yeah. I don't have an EF Core environment set up so Its hard for me to test, but your probably right.